# What is the cleanest way to create a non-linear pipeline?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, pipelining

What is the cleanest (simplest, most efficient, shortest, quickest, easiest, most elegant) way to create a non-linear pipeline like this in Bash?

I have three commands: `mksock`, `irclogin`, and `ircpingpong`. I want to pipe `stdin`, `irclogin`, and `ircpingpong` into `mksock`, and pipe `mksock` into `stdout` and `ircpingpong`. This means that `mksock` and `ircpingpong` are in a loop. I drew a diagram:

[image: Diagram]

*irclogin* only needs to be run once and be the first input into *mksock*. After that, *ircpingpong*, and *stdin* should be accepted at any time. I am currently using pipes and a temporary file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

server=127.0.0.1
port=6667

infifo=/tmp/ircin
outfifo=/tmp/ircout
pongfifo=/tmp/ircpong

rm $infifo
rm $outfifo
rm $pongfifo
mkfifo $infifo
mkfifo $outfifo
touch $pongfifo

( irclogin | cat - $infifo & tail -f $pongfifo; ) | mksock $server $port | tee $outfifo | stdbuf -oL ircpingpong > $pongfifo &
cat < $outfifo &
cat > $infifo
pkill tail
```

This *works*, but I want to know if there is a better way to do this. It bothers me that I am using a file rather than a pipe for looping back from *ircpingpong* to *mksock* using tail. Using a pipe didn't work because, to my understanding, something is written to the pipe before `tail -f` starts reading from it, and so it misses it.

It also bothers me that I have to kill tail at the end of the script, because it doesn't stop on it's own and would leave the socket connected even after the script has ended.

Comment: This is what Coproceses are for.  They are supported differently on Korn shell and bash, bash coprocesses were introduced in bash 4.0.  See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest a version without temporary files, and with two fifo-s:

```
fifo1=/tmp/fifo1
fifo2=/tmp/fifo2
rm $fifo1
rm $fifo2
mkfifo $fifo1
mkfifo $fifo2

ircpingpong < $fifo2 > $fifo1 &
(mksock <$fifo1|tee $fifo2 )&
irclogin >$fifo1 &
cat >$fifo1
```

The idea is to run all programs separately, and only ensure that input and output of each program is redirected properly according to this diagram:

[image: pipe-flow]

Of course, `ircpingpong` must read `stdin` and write to `stdout`, `irclogin` must write to `stdout`, and `mksock` must read from `stdin` and write to `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that uses just one fifo.

```
fifo=/tmp/myfifo
rm $fifo
mkfifo $fifo

((ircpingpong < $fifo &) && irclogin && cat) | mksock | tee $fifo
```

Add stdbuf as needed.

I don't know whether you will get your "something doesn't die on its own" problem; when I ctrl-c'ed the script, everything seemed to die.